# Cannot change font color of all elements within rows and columns in table tags

Tags: html, fonts, html-table, android-webview

I am trying to change font color of different web elements in different areas. Mostly it works fine while I am using I am using like this:

```
<font color='BLUE'>
<DIV>
<SPAN style="WHITE-SPACE: normal; TEXT-TRANSFORM: none; WORD-SPACING: 0px; FLOAT: none;      : rgb(34,34,34); FONT: 13px Calibri; -webkit-text-size-adjust: auto">
</SPAN>
</DIV>
<DIV>
<SPAN style="BORDER-TOP-     : ; WHITE-SPACE: normal; TEXT-TRANSFORM: none; WORD-SPACING: 0px; FLOAT: none;      : rgb(0,0,0); FONT: large arial, sans-serif;  -webkit-text-size-adjust: auto">abc
</SPAN>
</DIV>
</font>
```

or just

```
 <font color='BLUE'>
<P>abc
</P>
    </font>
```

BUT when I am trying to change font color and formation of some text elements which are under  tags, it dorsn't work!

```
<font color='Blue'>
        <DIV>   
        <TABLE style="WIDTH: 165pt; BORDER-COLLAPSE: collapse; border=0 cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0 width=219>
        <COLGROUP>
        <COL style="WIDTH: 21pt; mso-width-source: userset; mso-width-alt: 1024" width=28>
        <COL style="WIDTH: 92pt; mso-width-source: userset; mso-width-alt: 4498" width=123>
        <TBODY>
        <TR style="HEIGHT: 66pt; mso-height-source: userset" height=88>
        <TD style="BORDER-BOTTOM: #ece9d8; BORDER-LEFT: #ece9d8;           -     : transparent; WIDTH: 165pt; HEIGHT: 66pt; BORDER-TOP: #ece9d8; BORDER-RIGHT: #ece9d8" class=xl65 height=88 width=219 colSpan=4><FONT size=2 face=Calibri></FONT>
        </TD></TR>
        <TR style="HEIGHT: 107.25pt; mso-height-source: userset" height=143>
        <TD style="BORDER-BOTTOM: #ece9d8; BORDER-LEFT: #ece9d8;           -     : transparent; WIDTH: 165pt; HEIGHT: 107.25pt; BORDER-TOP: #ece9d8; BORDER-RIGHT: #ece9d8" class=xl65 height=143 width=219 colSpan=4>
        <FONT size=2 face=Calibri>
        <SPAN style="mso-spacerun: yes">&nbsp; </SPAN><BR><BR></FONT></TD></TR>
        </TBODY>
        </TABLE>
        </DIV>
        </font>
```

Please suggest me what should I do if I want to keep generic rule to change font colors for all sort of formats. This is I have been using in some app where I am getting inputs from user where they have been inserting texts within html tags, I just need to make the font color similar for the texts and keep the same format for all the inputs.

P.S. To make the scenario clear, From the server end I am actually getting all the html tags and the texts, adding  at the begin and end of the string, loading the new String into a webview like this:

```
String str = "abc"; //actaully what I am getting from backend with html tags

if(ann.get() != null)

    String  content = "<font color='Blue'>";
    content = content + Str;
    content = content + "</font>";
    details.loadData(content,"text/html","UTF-8");
    details.setBackgroundColor(Color.Black);
```

Comment: FONT statements were deprecated a long time ago. Use CSS.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. This is I have been using in some app where I am getting inputs from user where they have been inserting portion of html files, I am just trying to keep the font color and format in similar way. I don't really know how I can use css within the android app! I just need to make the font color similar for the texts which comes with html tags.

Comment: Not that it is good practice, but if you really cannot use CSS, maybe you can wrap the whole thing in a `<span>` that has the same style? This should cascade properly.

Answer (score 1):

Give appropriate classes to your elements and then you can use CSS to style those classes.

For example

```
table {color: white}
td.myclass {color: green}
```

Comment: As Vlad and others point out use CSS.  Let the machines do the work.  The cascading part of Cascading Style Sheets reduces the need to transmit all of the STYLE tag content over the longest network connection in a web application, the connection between the browser and the server.  AND the cascading reduces the amount of hand-coding style bits.  AND the cascading means you program intent, what the style should be by element or class, rather than line-by-line applying that intent.  Win-Win-Win.

Comment: To make the scenario clear, From the server end I am actually getting all the html tags and the texts, adding at the begin and end of the string, loading the new String into a webview like this:

String str = "abc"; //actaully what I am getting from backend with html tags

if(ann.getAnnouncementDetails() != null)

    String  content = "<font color='Blue'>";
    content = content + Str;
    content = content + "</font>";
    details.loadData(content,"text/html","UTF-8");
    details.setBackgroundColor(Color.Black);

Answer (score 1):

Markup that has a `div` or `table` element inside a `font` element is invalid according to all HTML specifications. Yet, browsers have traditionally digested it, but so that the font properties do not affect the content inside a table. This is still how modern browsers behave in [Quirks Mode](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/quirks-mode.html).

Oddly enough, in Standards Mode, modern browsers apply the font color on the table content. (So in the so-called Standards Mode, some nonstandard markup that is otherwise ignored is honored!) However, switching to Standards Mode, by slapping `<!doctype html>` at the very start of the document, is very hazardous. Code that has been developed to work in Quirks Mode may completely collapse in Standards Mode, or it may work almost the same, or something in between.

If you specifically want to set the color inside the tables of the page, you can add the following element:

```
<style>
th, td { color: blue }
</style>
```

It should go into the `head` part by HTML syntax, but in reality it works well in the `body` part, too, so you can slap it before (or after!) the table if you must.

Comment: To make the scenario clear, From the server end I am actually getting all the html tags and the texts, adding at <font> the begin and end of the string, loading the new String into a webview like this: String str = "abc"; //actaully what I am getting from backend with html tags if(ann.getAnnouncementDetails() != null) String content = "<font color='Blue'>"; content = content + Str; content = content + "</font>"; details.loadData(content,"text/html","UTF-8"); details.setBackgroundColor(Color.Black);

Comment: Confirmed this to be correct.  I tested my non-working table font color by adding <!doctype html>, and surely enough, the color changed.  Thanks!